# Immersion of $\mathbb RP^2$: explanation of Kirby's article on the Boy's surface

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, surfaces, projective-space, visualization

I am trying to understand Rob Kirby's AMS notice https://www.ams.org/notices/200710/tx071001306p.pdf on Boy's surface. From this blogpost https://divisbyzero.com/2020/04/08/make-a-real-projective-plane-boys-surface-out-of-paper/, I understand the octahedron construction of $\mathbb RP^2$.

[image: Kirby AMS octahedron real projective plane]

I have numbered the edges based on the foldable from the blogpost: (I have also colored the foldable's regions with the colors that appear in the above picture)

[image: octahedron projective plane foldable]

Kirby then writes the paragraph:

> The neighborhood of the top vertex is drawn
> in Figure 3. This neighborhood can be flattened
> out to look like the polyhedron in Figure 4; it is
> still a cone on a figure-8. A neighborhood of the
> red edge is homeomorphic to the polyhedron in
> Figure 5, having cones at both ends. Flattening
> then gives the polyhedron Q in Figure 6. Q is
> the image of a rectangle, immersed except at the
> cone points. This can be changed, relative to the
> boundary, to the immersed image of a rectangle
> as in Figure 7, where the two cone points have
> been canceled.

[image: smoothing octahedron construction of RP2]

[image: smoothing construction 2]

I have drawn in Kirby's red line in the foldable picture above. **But I have no idea what he is talking about when he says Figure 3 can be flattened into Figure 4**. Did the blue triangle turn into a blue square? What does the gray plane correspond to?

If at all possible, I would appreciate if someone could explain what Kirby is saying; maybe sketching some intermediate diagrams, or taking pictures of a physical model (that one can create by printing, folding and labelling/coloring the foldable)