# Embedding/immersion of $\mathbb RP^2$ into Euclidean space so lines are geodesics?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, surfaces, geometric-topology, projective-space, geodesic

The real projective plane $\mathbb RP^2$ is introduced in algebraic geometry contexts as basically $\mathbb R^2$ but where all lines intersect at one point. One construction is the one that projects the 3D-world onto our 2D field of vision (the [original starting point of the field](https://www.britannica.com/science/projective-geometry)?), by having an "eye" $E$ at $(0,0,1)$ looking down at the $xy$-plane, mapping each point $(x,y,0)$ to the intersection of the [line between $E$ and $(x,y,0)$] and the [(lower hemisphere of the) sphere $S$ centered at $(0,0,1)$], adding in "points at $\infty$" on the equator of $S$ (identifying antipodal points on that circle).

Lines passing through $(0,0,0)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ are obviously mapped to (half of a) great circles on $S$, and I'm pretty sure other lines in the $xy$-plane are also mapped to great circles on $S$ as well. This is nice, as great circles are geodesics on $S$, matching the notion of line in $\mathbb R^2$.

The bad thing is that this "model" of $\mathbb RP^2$ is not a continuous image of $\mathbb RP^2$ in $\mathbb R^3$. There are immersions of $\mathbb RP^2$ (I in fact [asked about it recently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4796758/immersion-of-mathbb-rp2-explanation-of-kirbys-article-on-the-boys-surface)); pictures of very nice ones can be found here: http://wordpress.discretization.de/ddg2019/2019/05/06/tutorial-4-boys-surface/. See [this animated video about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTpzDHWSiXk&ab_channel=YutoHorikawa) showing what it's like to move around on it. A different animated construction can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gRx66xKXek&ab_channel=DuleZiv).

[image: Boy's surface (Kusner and Bryant) image from DDG2019]

> **Question:** is there an immersion of $\mathbb RP^2$ into $\mathbb R^3$ so that lines (the great circles in the hemisphere model I described above) are geodesics on the immersed surface?